# Punctuation issues with relative pronouns

Tags: punctuation

Is it allowed to replace the highlighted words in the following sentence with a comma?

1. This is the book **which was** stolen by Taro.
2. This is the book, stolen by Taro.

Comment: Why comma even?

Comment: Have you asked on ell.stackexchange.com for Learners?

Comment: See my comment below for a site where you can see videos that explain all aspects of grammar and punctuation. I recommend engVid.com to all my tutoring students. They have a search feature as well as categories to choose from. For videos specific to writing, under the all lessons tab, choose the writing category and the all three levels of proficiency. They have (right now) 591 teaching videos, and they add more weekly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, both sentences are grammatical but convey different meanings. In the first sentence the relative clause is a *defining* (or *restrictive*) clause that defines or identifies the book. It answers the implied question: *Which of these books is the book that Taro stole?*

The second sentence could be expanded to:

> This is the book, which was stolen by Taro.

In this case, the comma indicates that the relative clause is a *non-defining* (*non-restrictive*) clause that gives extra information about the book. It is akin to saying:

> This is the book I was talking about, and by the way, it was stolen by
>   Taro.

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatical, but might be used in different contexts. Neither needs any commas, if, as seems likely, the purpose of *which was stolen by Taro* in the first and *stolen by Taro* in the second is to tell us which book the writer means. But, as Shoe says, if *stolen by Taro* in (2) is merely providing additional information, then a comma would be required, but not if it is intended to have the same meaning as (1).

Answer (score 1):

There is a literary way of looking at this that could be extrapolated from the two sentences. I read it four ways, two of which use commas:

```
This is the book stolen by Taro
```

I pictured a detective entering the squad room and putting a book on the Captain's desk. He has just recovered the book, and is about to discuss its contents, because it contains controversial information that might be a lead into some other investigation. No comma is needed.

Or `This book was stolen by Taro`

In this case it would be as if a librarian were saying it was plagiarized, or that Taro, a famous thief, stole the manuscript, and it was recreated or recovered.

Or `This is the book, which was stolen by Taro.`

In this case, a curator is showing the book to someone and commenting on its provenance.

The last possibility that I see is your second sentence:

```
This is the book, stolen by Taro.
```

In this case, I see an underworld flunky handing a book to the mob boss and telling him they finally got hold of a book that outlined their nefarious operations, and they had it stolen by Taro, a thief, to keep it out of the cops' hands.

Any of these are correct, but it depends on the circumstances, the speaker, the book, and the thief. It is up to you to decide which fits.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your valuable elucidation. This comma issue is killing my writing. Could you please suggest a good website to get my doubts clarified on punctuations.

Comment: @user54162, The Online Writing Lab at Purdue University is a recommended resource for writers and contains this excellent overview on comma use: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/607/02/ .

Comment: If you need help after looking at the Purdue Owl. There are videos on English Grammar and Punctuation at engVid.com. I found this one:

Comment: Oops. The video is here: http://www.engvid.com/commas-punctuation-english-writing/   And they have other videos on grammar if you click on the all lessons button at the top and fill in the parameters for what you want to see. I use these for tutoring homework for the students I tutor. They can view the videos as many times as they need until they understand.